# How can I replace the existing primary key with a new primary key on my table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, database-schema

I'm working with a legacy SQL Server database which has a core table with a bad primary key.

The key is of type `NVARCHAR(50)` and contains an application-generated string based on various things in the table.  For obvious reasons, I'd like to replace this key with an auto-incrementing (identity) `INT` column.

This is a huge database and we're upgrading it piece-by-piece. We want to minimize the changes to tables that other components write to. I figured I could change the table without breaking anything by just:

1. Adding the new Id column to the table and making it nullable
2. Filling it with unique integers and making it `NOT NULL`
3. Dropping the existing primary key while ensuring there's a uniqueness constraint still on that column
4. Setting the new Id column to be the new primary key and identity

Item 3 is proving very painful.  Because this is a core table, there are a *lot* of other tables with foreign key constraints on it.  To drop the existing primary key, it seems I have to delete all these foreign key constraints and create them again afterwards.

**Is there an easier way to do this or will I just have to script everything?**

Comment: Quick questions: 1. When you say dropping this primary key you don't mean dropping the column, correct? 2. Did you try disabling the Foreign Key constraints on the other tables: ALTER TABLE <table_name>  NOCHECK CONSTRAINT <foreignkey_name>. This might help you get through to point 4 and when done reenable the fk constraints

Comment: 1. Correct - I actually want to keep all the foreign key constraints as is. I haven't tried disabling them, but the error suggests I need to actually delete them. I could try it though?

Comment: No, I don't think you need to delete them at all. Just disable them, do your thing and reenable them again. The script linked by @ericb does exactly the same thing. ALTER TABLE <table_name>
    NOCHECK CONSTRAINT 
        <fk_name> to disable  and ALTER TABLE <table_name>
    CHECK CONSTRAINT 
        <fk_name> to enable

Comment: Ok, I tried disabling them and then making the changes. Unfortunately it failed as soon as I tried to remove the primary key. The drop and recreate method worked though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afraid that is the bad news. We just got through a big project of doing the same type of thing, although our head DBA had a few tricks up his sleeve. You might look at something like [this](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1376) to get your scripts generated for the flipping of the switch:

Comment: Thanks. This is what I ended up using.

Answer (score 1):

I once did the same thing and basically used the process you describe.  Except of course you have to first visit each other table and add new foreign key pointing to the new column in your base table

So the approach I used was

1. Add a new column with an auto incrementing integer in the base table, ensure it has a unique index on it (to be replaced later by the primary key)
2. For each foreign key relationship pointing to the base table add a new column in the child table.  (note this can result in adding more than one column in the child table if more than one relationship)
3. For each instance of a key in the child table enter a value into the new foreign key field(s)
4. Replace your foreign key relationships such that the new column now serves
5. Make the new column in the base table the primary
6. Drop the old  primary key in the base table and each old foreign key in the
   children.

It is doable and not as hard as it might sound at first.  The crux is a series of update statements for the children table of the nature

```
Update child_table
set new_column = (select new_primary from base)
where old_primary = old_foreign
```

Comment: Yeah, I like that strategy. Unfortunately because we're only doing it a little bit at a time, I don't want to change these foreign key references. For the moment, I'm ok with leaving them pointing at the old key. We'll cross that bridge when we update those tables.

Comment: I faced the same issue.  I still built the foreign keys first.  It took months for item 6 to happen but that means for a period maintaining both sets of keys.  You will still have to be able to add new foriegn key relations and have them work.  I do think faster is better.  Prove on concept with 2-3 tables and then go hard.